# how to make ZBarReaderViewController fullScreen

Tags: objective-c, ios, barcode-scanner

I want to make my `ZBarReaderViewController` full screen.
I use this code:

```
_reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
_reader.readerDelegate = self;
_reader.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
_reader.readerView.showsFPS = YES;
_reader.readerView.allowsPinchZoom = YES;
_reader.showsCameraControls = NO;
_reader.showsZBarControls = NO;
_reader.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
_reader.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
_reader.cameraViewTransform = translate;        
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 1.5, 1.5);
_reader.cameraViewTransform = scale;
[_reader.scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0]; 
[self presentModalViewController:_reader animated:YES];
```

but result reader View is not display as full screen as I expected.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: are you using cameraOverlayView?
reader.cameraOverlayView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are having this problem on iPad only?

I had the same problem and managed to fix it by using the latest ZBarSDK beta version. Please see my answer to a similar question here: [zbarsdk ZBarReaderViewController - set full screen for ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961718/zbarsdk-zbarreaderviewcontroller-set-full-screen-for-ipad)