# zbarsdk ZBarReaderViewController - set full screen for ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, zbar-sdk

I am not able to display the zbarsdk reader in full screen on iPad.

It keeps showing in the top left hand corner.

I have tried the following

```
reader.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
reader.cameraOverlayView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, X, Y); //X and Y are iPad dimensions
[reader.cameraOverlayView sizeToFit];
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the solution did come from the zbar sourceforge forums. iPad full screen support is only supported in their latest beta version. To get this, go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/iPhoneSDK/beta/ and download the latest beta (I used ZBarSDK-1.2.2.dmg)

I replaced the existing ZBarSDK files in my project with these, and it worked perferctly

Comment: Nice to see that you found the solution and sorry was not able to respond as it was weekend :) , anyways best of luck \m/

Comment: @Vedran ..I  integrated  ZBardSDK-1.2.2.dmg as follow you I got full ipad screen but I am not able to read the Barcode/QRcode .. Please help me .. put your code..I hope that will help me...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps out http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html and do look at this : Scandit SDK barcode scanner from http://www.scandit.com/. Their latest version was updated to optimally support the iPad 2.

Comment: thanks @Suhaiyl. Scandit is not an option for me, but your link to the forum looks like it is on the right path. Following some of the suggestions there I still can't get this to work. I'll keep trying and will post an answer if I find one...in the meantime, if anyone can help with actual code, would be much appreciated

Comment: please see my answer to this question (+1 to you for guiding me in the right direction)...had to download the latest beta SDK and it now works